# How to use the geometry proximity node as snapping tool

Tags: geometry-nodes, snapping

I want to use geometry nodes as a snapping tool. Here is a simple example of the problem:
The **geometry proximity** node uses the shortest distance. How can I make it use the distance in the direction of the normal of each face?

[image]

small shape I want to deform:
[image]

big shape I want to snap to:

[image]

result of geometry proximity using the shortest distance:
[image]

[image]

I have added the file, I hope I shared it correcly in this way.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you would have to use the node `Raycast`:

[image]

With this you can feed the direction of the ray with the normals of the faces, whereby along this the position of the nearest object can be queried and used as position for `Set Position`.